# Measuring activity on an invision prototype?

Tags: usability-testing, prototype, ab-testing

I'm wondering if any of you all could help me with this predicament.

I am about to finish a certificate in human-computer interaction and the final gauntlet is A/B testing the prototypes we have built throughout the course. The prototyping was left to our discretion and since my web development isn't nearly as good as would be needed to actually build the site, I chose to use invision as it served my needs better than pixate would.

The test needs to be on at least 20 people but my bigger problem is measuring conversions. Does anybody know of a way to do this online? I've thought of hosting it on my own website and then adding some third party tools like analytics but I don't believe it will register the clicks from an embed (although it may, in which case problem solved) if anybody knows for sure please tell me. I have also thought about just doing in person non-usability tests with the built in invision mobile testing software, but that would severely limit the quality of data retrieved.

Its pretty strange performing an A/B test without a user-base for a service that doesn't exist so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you are measuring conversion, then you need to explain what the tasks are and what you have designed in terms of the screens to work out how to test it. A/B testing seems to be a strange test to perform for measuring conversion, as there usually is a path that needs to be tested, not a comparison between different types of screen designs. But if it is something like sign-up or a purchase call-to-action then maybe it makes more sense. But we definitely need more details.

Comment: This is something I am weary of as well. AB testing something that doesn't technically exist just seems backwards since there isn't any regular traffic with their own priorities. Ive been thinking about simply posting a link to the particular prototype and giving them a background on the site.

I have already had to usability test it to this point and since this is, for all practical reasons, hypothetical, I decided to make version a focus on increasing posting rate and version b on discovering posts. The original and unaltered version will also be figured in.

Comment: I am unsure how to outline tasks without explicitly treating it like the usability test script, in which it would nullify the point of the actual tests and would instead speak to efficiency. I should also add that I am not explicitly measuring conversion, in fact it isn't even mentioned in the assignment. I am measuring general clicks, conversion to posting user, and page progression.

Comment: As I continue with this endless string of comments I cannot help but feel it is digressing from the main reason I made this post: inquiring on how to measure activity of an invision prototype rather than how to actually measure conversions. I have updated the title to help clarify this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Loop11. The last time I tried their service, I was able to send users to any linkable prototype (external). You tell Loop11 which link on the website is the correct one for the conversion, and they will register it. They time it as well. You simply come up with the task questions and any follow up questions, and they handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you have any input as to how I should phrase the tasks if I were to use the service, seeing as it is primarily usability and I am looking for AB results. I know that sounds idiotic, but thats pretty much the assignment guidelines (still doesn't really make sense to me). I don't think I can give super explicit tasks otherwise it pretty much overtakes AB with usability. Maybe something like explore the site? That seems extremely broad though but it seems to be the only way to conduct AB without an actual userbase.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood. If your assignment is to do an A/B test on at least 20 users for an Invision prototype, then using Loop11 is not the right tool. If you can figure a way to create two different prototypes in Invision with a testable link for each, then you should be able to use one of the tools specified in this article to conduct your A/B test. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-a-b-testing/

Comment: Another thing to think about is that whatever tool you use, if it requires that you have access to the code in order to copy/paste some javascript, then I think you may need to reconsider using something other than Invision for your prototype. Invision (as far as I know) doesn't give you access to the prototype's HTML/JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

First of I have to state that I haven't tried this myself (yet). However, I have heard from alot of people having tried this solution with success.

There is an online tool called **Try My UI** that supports user testing with InVision.

I won't explain the process here since this link explains it well enough: http://blog.trymyui.com/2016/04/prototype-testing-with-invision-trymyui/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With 20 testers, you won't be able to get statistically significant A/B test results. I see two things you could try to assess the performance of your three variations.

**Remote user testing**

Use a service like UserTesting, UserBrain, TryMyUi, etc. that offers remote user testing services. You can then watch the videos of users visiting your InVision mock-up and get qualitative insights about how they perform. You can even manually track the "conversions" from the videos.

**Tracking final conversions**

While it isn't possible (to my knowledge) to track click events inside an InVision mock-up, you could easily track the final click of your users, by making it an external link. You could use "one-click survey" services such as YesInsights, to generate three different links, that you could use in your three mock-ups. You will then be able to track the number of clicks on each of the links.